# How to create a link using Pages online (iCloud)

Tags: pages

I don't see any of the usual text options while editing a Pages doc in iCloud online.

[image]

Cmd-L and Cmd-K both don't work.

How can I add a link to text using the iCloud version of Pages?

Comment: Looks to me like you can't, though links do auto-create when you input a url like `https://google.com`.

Comment: @owlswipe I saw that. Unfortunately it is a google docs links, so it is long and ugly.

Comment: you could convert it to a https://bit.ly link or a https://goo.gl link! Or get the full version of pages on any Mac/iOS device.

Comment: And you can customize bitly links with a free account, so for instance you can go download one of my apps at https://bit.ly/primecalc (shameless plug :D)

Comment: Not an ideal solution, **but** if you have MS Word you can create your doc with hyperlinks there and then drag the doc into Pages. This preserves the pre-existing hyperlinks. Unfortunately, if you need to edit the hyperlinks later, you need to go back into MS Word again. Like I said, not ideal. But I'd certainly recommend you sending [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages-for-icloud.html) about this!

Answer (score 1):

Just got off the phone with Apple Support, and you cannot make hyperlinks in the iCloud online version of Pages as of Feb 23rd, 2017

This is particularly bad, because it is a document that is edited by 4 coworders, and owned by a VP. So to fix the hyperlinks, I have to get the VP to fix it on his computer, or download a copy, fix the links, and then convince everyone to stop using the old link. This is even harder because the link is the only way to access the shared doc. So it becomes the 'use this link, not this link, is this the most upto date attachment' problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem the solution is for someone to pony up and buy a Mac, since Pages is included free, these days. The Pages development team might eventually add this feature, but they haven't yet (January 25, 2018). In fact, I ended up here in an effort to solve the same issue. I have a desktop version of Pages, so I could go that route, though I'll likely just paste the URL and let Pages auto-link it.

Update: Pages for iCloud does support footnotes (click the paragraph icon and choose Footnote from the options). So I've added my URLs as footnotes. That actually has some advantages--especially for people who print out documents--over hyperlinking the words themselves.